# Why is 楽しみに！wrong?

Tags: grammar

I was corrected on Lang-8 website that I should write 楽しみ！or 楽しみにしています！instead of 楽しみに！. And I don't understand why.

Help please. 教えてくださいませんか。

Comment: What made you think it might be right?

Comment: At the end of anime episode they usually write 次回お楽しみに or つづく.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're talking about yourself you can't really use it that way. Ending it with に makes it sound like a kind of friendly request, like in お大事に. As such it sounds like you're telling someone "楽しみにしてください" because of the に ending. For yourself you just say 楽しみ or 楽しみにしています. Generally do not leave a に dangling by itself at the end to refer to your own feelings.

I'll piggyback off of Chocolate's beautiful comment for extra clarity:

- 楽しみです and 楽しみにしています represent the speaker's feelings as the subject of the sentence. So "I" am looking forward to something. This is shortened to 楽しみ in casual speech.
- お楽しみに, on the other hand, is a shortened way of saying 楽しみにしていてください, addressed *to* someone, a way of telling someone to look forward to something. It has an imperative feel.

Comment: Thanks. That's quite interesting. But what makes 楽しみにしています different?

Comment: @dimadesu It's just a full sentence that removes ambiguity. お楽しみに is a way of saying 楽しみにしてください, so if you say just that then it will be interpreted that way and thus seem odd.

Comment: @dimadesu 楽しみ! is the shortened form of 楽しみです, similar in meaning to 楽しみにしています. The subject for 楽しみです and 楽しみにしています is the speaker, ("I" am looking forward~~/私は○○が楽しみです/私は○○を楽しみにしています), whereas the subject in お楽しみに(+ね)! and 楽しみにしていてください is "you", the hearer(s), cos these are more like the imperative.

Comment: @ssb:Chocolate's answer is worth adding to yours to make it complete.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly certain 楽しみに is fine and they corrected it to that because it's just "the proper way" to say it. Japanese people do that a lot.
If you say でしょ they'll likely correct it with でしょう etc. even though Japanese people will use でしょ more often than not.